# How do I get Download URL from StorageReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my project, I am able to `getDownloadUrl()` after uploading a file

```
ref.putFile(imgUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {

                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        if(task.getException() != null) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }
                    }

                    return ref.getDownloadUrl();

                }
            }) ...
```

However, since I am resizing the image with a cloud function and re-uploading it to the bucket, the download url will change, so the only way to know the location of the image is through a `StorageReference`. How can I `getDownloadUrl()` from `StorageReference`? I've tried `ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener` which doesn't get fired and `ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener` and the `task.getResult()` throws an error.

Comment: You will need to establish some communication channel between your app the the function that makes the modification.  You have a lot of options for this, for example, Cloud Messaging, or a known location in a database where status is recorded.  In any event, it's not trivial to set up.

Comment: Hey Doug. We meet again. The images are linked to specific users. I guess I will need to splice the folder tree the image is uploaded to and set the download url in the database. thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this : 
I was trying to store images

You can get the download URL from task.getResult().toString()

```
    final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images").child(imageName)
uploadTask = ref.putBytes(data);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            String URL = task.getResult().toString();

        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
    });
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, but I was trying to figure out how to get the download url without uploading. After uploading my image, the cloud function resizes it and then puts it back in the bucket, deleting the original uploaded image.